# Aggregation involving sum of array field(s) and normal field(s) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

This is the sample collection:

```
{'f1': 10, '_id': 1, 'key': 'g', 'items': [{'i1': 10}, {'i1': 10}, {'i1': 10}]}
{'f1': 10, '_id': 2, 'key': 'g', 'items': [{'i1': 10}, {'i1': 10}, {'i1': 10}]}
{'f1': 77, '_id': 3, 'key': 'g', 'items': [{'i1': 10}, {'i1': 10}, {'i1': 10}]}
```

I want a formula like: `$sum(f1 + Σ[items.i1])` to be computed on the above collection. Following is what I could come up with (in pymongo):

```
db.collec.aggregate([    
        { "$unwind" : "$items"},
    { "$group" : {    
             "_id" : {"key": "$key", "id": "$_id"},    
     "matches" : { "$sum" : "$items.i1" },    
     "extra" : { "$sum" : "$f1" },    
     "count" : {"$sum": 1}    
                    }},
    { "$group": {    
             "_id" : "$_id.key",     
             "finalSum":{ "$sum":    
                        { "$add": ["$matches", {"$divide":["$extra", "$count"]}]}}}}      
    ]);
```

**Output:**

```
{'finalSum': 187.0, '_id': 'g'}
```

Although this gives correct output, I hope there's a better, simpler solution for this:
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are grouping the documents, you can save "f1" to the _id field, so that you don't need to summarize it and divide it for each document.

The aggregation operation is like this:

```
db.collec.aggregate([    
    { "$unwind" : "$items"},
    { "$group" : {    
          _id : {key: "$key", id: "$_id", f1 : "$f1" },    
          matches : { "$sum" : "$items.i1" },    
    }},
    { "$group": {    
          _id : "$_id.key",     
          finalSum : { "$sum":    
                        { "$add": ["$matches", "$_id.f1"]}}}}      
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks Linda. This seems to be a better solution. However I'm wondering about the 16mb document limit possibly disallowing this in-case of huge number of records and sufficient unique `key` - `f1` combinations. Also, is there any standard way to this? Other than writing multiple `$group` ?